# XML Parser for editing XML content in Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I'm new to XML Development. I was wondering if anyone on here knows what's the best XML parser to use for adding contents into an XML document in Java?

Comment: I have always used http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/ and here are some samples with this parser http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/samples.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding or modifying contents, I would look at a DOM parser.  [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks. Any help on where I can get an example of how to modify XML content with a DOM parser?

Comment: http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html this provides an example of creating a new document all together.  There's no reason you couldn't parse a document and then modify the instance using the examples here.